# Timezone de México en moment

Tags: javascript, nodejs, momentjs

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en `nodejs` y las fechas son un dolor de cabeza.

Estoy usando `moment` para controlarlo, pero algo me está fallando. cuando hago `moment().getDate()` esto me regresa la fecha del servidor donde esta corriendo y no quiero eso. Necesito poner por default el timezone de México, que si mal no estoy es `'America/Mexico_city'` nunca lo he hecho así que leyendo me encontré con esta instrucción

```
moment().utcOffset(-360).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Esto me regresa correctamente la fecha y hora actual, pero es un string, y mi modelo de base de datos no acepta strings, si no tipos Date. (Estoy usando MongoDB y mongoose) entonces lo hace incompatible para guardar.

Intenté hacer `new Date( moment().utcOffset(-360).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') )` pero regresa de nuevo a la fecha del servidor.

Soy novato con las fechas así que todas las sugerencias son bienvenidas.

Answer (score 0):

El tipo Date no tiene timezone, siempre usa UTC. De la documentación de Mozilla:

> A JavaScript date is fundamentally specified as the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since midnight on January 1, 1970, UTC

Por ejemplo:

```js
const now = new Date();

console.log(now.toLocaleString('es-MX',{ timeZone: 'UTC', dateStyle: "short", timeStyle: 'full' }));
console.log(now.toLocaleString('es-MX',{ timeZone: 'Europe/Madrid', dateStyle: "short", timeStyle: 'full'}));
console.log(now.toLocaleString('es-MX',{ timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo', dateStyle: "short", timeStyle: 'full'}));

console.log("Millis", now.getTime())
```

Realmente lo que se va a guardar en la base de datos es el número de milisegundos

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo leer sobre moment-timezone y luxon.
Ambas son buenas librerías que permiten el uso de distintas timezones.
He visto que es buena práctica guardar las fechas siempre en UTC, y luego manipularlas según sea necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui Puedes ver todos los time Zones

https://gist.github.com/diogocapela/12c6617fc87607d11fd62d2a4f42b02a

Si te fijas México tiene varios

- America/Tijuana
- America/Hermosillo
- America/Mazatlan
- America/Mexico_City

etc..

y se puede utilizar

```
moment().tz("America/Tijuana").format()
```

Espero te sirva de algo.